# Geometric sequence printing... Freaking out

Tags: c, numbers, sequence

My professor gave me this incomplete code to fill things out..
The answer that if I type in command prompt, it should show 3+ 6+ ... +48 = 93, EXACTLY. So I typed in my answer. See below

### command prompt

3 2 5 (typed. 3 = first number . 2 = multiplying number. n= number of elements)

3 + 6 + 12 + 24 + 48 = 93

If you want to continue. blah blah......

---

The problem below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, r, n;
    int s, ai, i;

    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &r, &n);

    s = 0;
    ai = a;
    for (i = 0; _________) {
        _____________________
        _____________________
        _____________________
        ______________________
    }
    printf(" = %d\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

---

My answer!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, r, n;
    int s, ai, i;

    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &r, &n);

    s = 0;
    ai = a;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i != n - 1)
            printf("%d + ", ai = ai*r*(i));
        else printf("%d", ai);
        s += ai;
    }
    printf(" = %d\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

You see, I'm not having a trouble with "+" thing because for the final element, it does not need to have "+" sign following number. so I can just put (i!=n-1) in order to make difference. For sum you can easily get it. All was fine... until I saw that (i=0) couldn't be changed and formula for calculating specific element of geometric sequence couldn't be used because formula would usually be a = a*r*(i-1). so I tried another way such as "ai = ai + r*i" but this makes sum of elements, not individual... i=0 makes such a difficulty for me and I can't even change it... He would mark it as wrong. And incomplete lines inside "for " loop should be exactly 4 LINES!!! (so even I made "else" and "else condition" in one line to make it 4 lines....

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your question is pretty badly worded and unclear to understand. Please try to rephrase it. And usng an assignment expression as a function argument is a very bad idea in general.

Answer (score 1):

there are could be different variants, here is one of them:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%s", i==0 ? "" : " + ");
    printf("%d", ai);
    s += ai;
    ai *= r;
}
```

another variant is to move calculations into loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++, s += ai, ai *= r) {
    if (i > 0)
        printf(" + %d", ai);
    else
        printf("%d", ai);
}
```

Comment: What is "?" sign. could you explain please?

Comment: @ChanyoungNathanLee [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Comment: @ChanyoungNathanLee: If you don't know that operator, you should revert to an `if` statement.

Comment: Then it makes more than 4 lines. That's the problem...

Comment: And we didn't lean about "%s" neither ( we learned %d though)

Comment: Although I can see it is string

Comment: @ChanyoungNathanLee you can replace it with `if (i > 0) printf(" + ");`

Answer (score -1):

One of the way to solve this problem is below .

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, r, n;
    int i=0; 
scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &r, &n);
   int ai=a;


for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

    a= a + (ai*i*r);
}
printf(" = %d\n", a);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why downvote?Is there a reason ? This is a tested program and it is working fine .